Ansible debug module : display debug message only once no matter hosts count
I would like to display a debug message in my playbook.
This is my playbook:
[blablabla]
- debug:
    msg:
    - "######################################################################"
    - "                    DIAGNOSTIC AGENT INSTALLATION                     "
    - "######################################################################"
[blablabla]

When I run this playbook on multiple target , the debug message on console output is displayed as many times as hosts count (as intended).
TASK [sifac-sap-diagnosticagent : debug] *******
task path: /etc/ansible/xxxxxx/tasks/main.yml:158
ok: [server1] => {
    "msg": [
        "######################################################################",
        "                    DIAGNOSTIC AGENT INSTALLATION                     ",
        "######################################################################"
    ]
}
ok: [server2] => {
    "msg": [
        "######################################################################",
        "                    DIAGNOSTIC AGENT INSTALLATION                     ",
        "######################################################################"
    ]
}
ok: [server3] => {
    "msg": [
        "######################################################################",
        "                    DIAGNOSTIC AGENT INSTALLATION                     ",
        "######################################################################"
    ]
}
ok: [server4] => {
    "msg": [
        "######################################################################",
        "                    DIAGNOSTIC AGENT INSTALLATION                     ",
        "######################################################################"
    ]
}


I would like to display this message only once, no matter hosts count. This in order to not overload my output.
Should I use option bypass_host_loop from debug ansible module ? Another method ?

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html

Use the run_once keyword on the task. It will run the task only for the first available host.
Look also for run_once in the playbook keywords.
[blablabla]
- debug:
  msg:
    - "######################################################################"
    - "                    DIAGNOSTIC AGENT INSTALLATION                     "
    - "######################################################################"
  run_once: true
[blablabla]

